# Symfony project Installation

Tags: symfony

I am trying to install Symfony inside my project folder by using this command: `composer create-project symfony/framework-standard-edition path/ "2.5.*"`.

During the set up I get prompted with a question if I want to install Aceme demo bundle which I reply to with yes, the installation continues but I get prompted again with these questions "look at the image":

[image]

As you can see I filled in all the details but this throws set of errors:

```
[Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\ContextErrorException]                                                                     

Warning: date_default_timezone_get(): It is not safe to rely on the system's
timezone settings. You are *required* to use the date.timezone setting or the
date_default_timezone_set() function. In case you used any of those methods 
and you are still getting this warning, you most likely misspelled the timezone
identifier. We selected the timezone 'UTC' for now, but please set date.timezone
to select your timezone. in
/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/Symfony/Project1/vendor/monolog/monolog/src/Monolog/Logger.php line 233
```

Script Sensio\Bundle\DistributionBundle\Composer\ScriptHandler::clearCache handling the post-install-cmd event terminated with an exception

```
[RuntimeException]                                                         
An error occurred when executing the "'cache:clear --no-warmup'" command. `
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: It's as the error says, set your `date.timezone` value in your `php.ini`

Comment: What is your PHP version?

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps a downside of using composer to create the project, you don't have a chance to go through the "Checking your System Configuration" section of the installation and fix errors before proceeding.

https://github.com/symfony/symfony-standard/tree/2.5#2-checking-your-system-configuration

If you run `php app/check.php` you'll see that you haven't met one of the mandatory requirements, which is to explicitly setting the `date.timezone` value in your system's **php.ini**

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem why the error was thrown xD

It was due to my php version I had installed on my mac (5.3)
Symfony requiers 5.5

Since I updated my version I dont see this error any more.

Thanks for yours help guys :)

Comment: Not really... the `composer.json` of Symfony 2.5 notes a requirement of `"php": ">=5.3.3"`. It probably just set the `date.timezone` value for you when you upgraded your PHP. Please try to understand your problems and make actual attempts at addressing them.

Comment: but it states it php 5.5 is preferable

Comment: Be aware that Symfony has some known limitations when using a PHP version less than 5.3.8 or equal to 5.3.16. For more information see the Requirements section of the README.

Comment: so it is possible that the version was the problem but it cannot be said 100% so suggest u might understand problems.....

Comment: [Here's the limitations you're believing is associated with `date.timezone`](https://github.com/symfony/symfony#requirements)